# Prove the existence of $n$ such that $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x_k^n $ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Ist the following statement true?

If $\left(x_k\right)_{k=0}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=0$, then there exists a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x_k^n
$$
is convergent.

I conjectured this after some thoughts about the zeta function, but I have no idea of how to prove it.

Comment: A counter-example is $x_k=\frac{1}{\log(k)}$ for $k\geq 2$: For all $n$, the series $\frac{1}{(\log k)^n}$ is divergent.

Comment: @Kelenner Why not make it an answer? It could prevent duplicate answers to come. :) As a comment, it can be overlooked.

Comment: @Gudson Chou: Thanks, but too late...

Comment: Sorry, I was typing my answer before I saw your comment. If you prefer, you can post an answer and I will delete mine.

Comment: No, I was not in the idea to write an answer, and your answer if fine, so do not delete it. Thank you for your proposition. (+1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x_k = \frac{1}{\ln(k)}$. Then $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} x_k^n = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln^n(k)}$ diverges for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. You can see that for example using Cauchy's condensation test:

$$ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} 2^k (x_{2^k})^n = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{\ln^n(2^k)} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{k^n \ln(2)^n} $$

which diverges because the general term of the series tends to $+\infty$ and so the original series diverges.